# how to perform load test and response tome of the sql database using jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Thanks for ur previous response it was really help full.
My application is a php based application using wamp server for my sql we have installed web application in that server . how i can test my application database stress and response time using jmeter.

Regards,
Bala

Answer (score 0):

You can use **JDBC Request sampler** to test your database server(Add  -->  Sampler  -->  JDBC Request) and  **JDBC Connection Configuration element** can add for database configuration (Add  -->  Config Element  -->  JDBC Connection Configuration).

Refer this [**website**](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-db-test-plan.html) for more information to build testplan

Answer (score 0):

Look a [this](http://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter) article, it can help you to build a database test plan with JMeter  http://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter